# Is there a way to ignore STL libraries when doing "step into" in the Android Studio debugger?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, stl

Debugging NDK code in Android Studio, it drives me nuts trying to "step into" a function where STL objects are involved. I wind up inside a twisty little maze of STL functions, all different. I need to hit "step into" dozens of times to actually reach the function being called.

I really don't need to look at this dozens of times:

```
template <class _Tp>
_LIBCPP_NODISCARD_EXT inline
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11
const _Tp&
min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
{
    return _VSTD::min(__a, __b, __less<_Tp>());
}
```

I want to debug my *own* code.

Comment: I have no better solution that _use step over when you're about to enter something you don't want_.

Comment: That's what I do sometimes, but every once in a while it turns out that the little bit of stl library I'm trying to ignore was a function wrapper that I needed to step further down into.

Comment: Worth noting: I did look into "smart step into", but it's greyed out. Maybe it's not available for C++?